# Get the index of the start of a newline in a Stringbuffer

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I need to get the starting position of new line when looping through a StringBuffer.
Say I have the following document in a stringbuffer

```
"This is a test
Test
Testing Testing"
```

New lines exist after "test", "Test" and "Testing".

I need something like:

```
for(int i =0;i < StringBuffer.capacity(); i++){
if(StringBuffer.chatAt(i) == '\n')
    System.out.println("New line at " + i);

}
```

I know that won't work because '\n' isn't a character. Any ideas? :)

Thanks

Comment: `'\n'` is a character.

Comment: It doesn't work because capacity() is not the same as length(). Please read documentation!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simplify your loop as such:

```
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("This is a\ntest, this\n\nis a test\n");

for (int pos = str.indexOf("\n"); pos != -1; pos = str.indexOf("\n", pos + 1)) {
  System.out.println("\\n at " + pos);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println("New line at " + stringBuffer.indexOf("\n"));
```

(no loop necessary anymore)

Comment: That will just print the index of the first `'\n'`. What about the others?

Comment: Thats what I need. For the others I could have a while loop and it will end when the indexOf is -1 :)

Comment: @Decrypter, you should have the for loop from beny23, as thats a nice idea.

Comment: Done something similar with a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine with a couple of syntactical modifications:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("This is a test\nTest\nTesting Testing");

    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        if (sb.charAt(i) == '\n')
            System.out.println("New line at " + i);
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
New line at 14
New line at 19
```